# Failed to load PDF document with dompdf

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2, pdf-generation, dompdf

i'm starting to code on zend framework 2 and using DOMPDF library to make a pdf generation of a html page. This just hello world and the result is a pdf that fails to load.
Here's my code

```
require_once('/home/ubuntu/learnzf2/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$html = "<html><body>Test</body></html>";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("test.pdf");
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I have replaced your code (basically the $html) in a controller where I generate PDFs and it works fine. Could you provide more information? Any error, PHP version, etc. You could check the **<dompdf_path>/lib/fonts/log.htm** log file

Comment: What do you mean a PDF that fails to load? Do you get any errors? Does the PDF generate? If it does, is your PDF viewer unable to open it?

Answer (score -2):

in your

```
<?php if(!isset(whatever))dir(); ?>
```

add this at above of code